# scraping Google Knowledge box with bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-search-api, google-search-console

I am trying to scrape google search results. Such that, go to google and search for "apple". You will see that there is a " Stock Price: AAPL" at the right column at the search results, in the knowledge box

I need to scrape AAPL from the search results. Once I inspect the source, I find it as "kno-fv".

```
page = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS916US916&ei=R3VZX_OGNvG9gge5n42YDw&q=apple&oq=aaple&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIQCC4QsQMQxwEQowIQQxCTAjIECAAQQzILCC4QsQMQxwEQowIyCAgAELEDEIMBMgQIABBDMgcIABCxAxBDMgUIABCxAzICCAAyBQgAELEDMggILhDHARCvAVAAWABgiiBoAHAAeACAAZIBiAGSAZIBAzAuMZgBAKoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwizxsCurN3rAhXxnuAKHblPA_MQ4dUDCA0&uact=5")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
ticker=soup.find('span', attrs={'class': "kno-fv"})
data = ticker.get_text()
```

However, it keeps giving me error or cannot find the "AAPL" .

Comment: the search result triggers a result that pull data from a source. you can also get info direct for googlefinance Pypi api. https://pypi.org/project/googlefinance/

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your kind help, John. I am trying to consider the existence of Stock price in the search results as a benchmark to identify if a company is public or not public. I have a list of 9000 companies.  the inspection is too much nested and I am confused. Do you have a chance to take a look?

Comment: Was just thinking The Google Knowledge box or panel doesn't always trigger and its hard to work around the captcha and but in this use case, it probably will. so if Nationwide Mutual Insurance has no stock price it is non-public and appl stock price true public.

Comment: So yes, very good point once again. I didnot know its name is google knowledge box, honestly. it is mostly paid api services suggested. do you have any suggestion for google knowledge box scrapping :)

Comment: Google uses JavaScript to display results but `requests` `BS` can't run JavaScript. As I remeber when Google sees that client can't use JavaScript then it sends different HTML with different classes, etc. Turn off JavScript in web browser and then search `apple` to see what your script gets.

Answer (score 2):

Google blocks without a proper user-agent header. I've passed user-agent string to `requests.get` from your code sample and it successfully extracts that AAPL ticker.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.87 Safari/537.36"
}

page = requests.get(
    "https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS916US916&ei=R3VZX_OGNvG9gge5n42YDw&q=apple&oq=aaple&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIQCC4QsQMQxwEQowIQQxCTAjIECAAQQzILCC4QsQMQxwEQowIyCAgAELEDEIMBMgQIABBDMgcIABCxAxBDMgUIABCxAzICCAAyBQgAELEDMggILhDHARCvAVAAWABgiiBoAHAAeACAAZIBiAGSAZIBAzAuMZgBAKoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwizxsCurN3rAhXxnuAKHblPA_MQ4dUDCA0&uact=5",
    headers=headers)
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
ticker = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': "kno-fv"})
data = ticker.get_text()

print(data)
```

**Output**

```
AAPL (NASDAQ) $139.07 +2.20 (+1.61%)Jan 22, 4:00 PM EST - Disclaimer
```

Alternatively, if you want to just access extracted data from search results without scraping Google, you can use [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com/knowledge-graph). It's a paid service with a free trial.

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "q": "Apple",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY")
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
data = search.get_dict()

ticker = data["knowledge_graph"]["stock_price"]

print(ticker)
```

**Output**

```
AAPL (NASDAQ) $139.07 +2.20 (+1.61%)Jan 22, 4 - 00 PM EST - Disclaimer
```

**Disclaimer**: I work at SerpApi.

Comment: Can I ask to you if SerpApi have the consent of Google for its api? Because Google can't be parsed and I want to use your api but I'm scared of legal consequences (reading the robots.txt).

Comment: @MatteoBianchi I'm not a lawyer but scraping public data has been legal in the United States only recently. See [hiQ v. Linkedin](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2019/09/victory-ruling-hiq-v-linkedin-protects-scraping-public-data). US Legal Shield is a product of ours that protects our customers from legal issues related to scrapping. This product is an extra layer of protection if the law changes again. It obviously won’t extend if your usage is otherwise illegal. For example, using our API to find targets for cyber offense is prohibited in [our ToS under Section 13](https://serpapi.com/legal).

Comment: Hi there, I was also skeptical about to proceed with scrapping or not. I have also read about the Linkedin story and then decided to write a module by extending this code to a company identifier which simply detects if a company is public or not from the SERP results. I am still not sure if this is legel or not. I am using that as a module to identify companies for  my research at a US university.